# How to test user log out using minitest and sessions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I am trying to test that a user has logged out using minitest and sessions. Below is the test:

```
test "can log out" do
  post site_customers_sign_in_url, params: customer_session_params
  delete site_customers_sign_out_path
  assert_redirected_to site_customers_sign_in_url
end
```

Running the test brings an error `` NoMethodError: undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass `` and having a `byebug` just just before the delete request and running the delete request in the byebug console brings an error `*** "Delete" argument "site_customers_sign_out_path" needs to be a number`. I have tried running `delete site_customers_sign_out_path(@customer)` but to no avail.